# Serialize JSON from object to string / byte[]

Tags: c#, string, blazor, byte, webapi

I'm having a problem in the frontend, because im trying to print a date but the type of the date is byte[].
So in order to fix the error i need to convert it into string.

This is the declaration of the date in the model:

```
public byte[]? AttemptDate { get; set; }
```

I tried to create a class to convert it:

```
public class ByteJsonConverter : JsonConverter<byte[]>
{
public override byte[] ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, byte[] existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    string base64String = (string)reader.Value;
    byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    return byteArray;
}

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, byte[] value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(value);
    writer.WriteValue(base64String);
}
```

}

And then call it this way:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ByteJsonConverter))]
public byte[]? AttemptDate { get; set; }
```

But it seems to not be working, can anyone fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: In the console it says this:
Unhandled exception rendering component: The converter specified on 'BusinessLogic.Entities.ExamAttempt.AttemptDate' does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor.
System.InvalidOperationException: The converter specified on 'BusinessLogic.Entities.ExamAttempt.AttemptDate' does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor.

There is more text in error, but is too extended to paste here.